# Python JIT instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is about instantiating object attributes **J**ust **i**n **T**ime.

I'm working on a REST API, where I currently create Python objects from the JSON data returned by the server, though not all attributes of the created objects will be called upon in user code. Hence only instantiating the attributes the user access via dot notation seems like a valid way to improve performance.

`lazy_evaluate` is a function, with a signature similar to `functools.partial`. 
`lazy_evaluate` returns a function that when called multiple times only computes the result once.

I then take advantage of the builtin `property` function to create a getter that calls the function returned by `lazy_evaluate`.

There is clearly a trade off here. This only helps performance if a subset of the attributes are required in user code. Otherwise the extra code will slow it down.

The core of the idea is to use Python scoping to mutate a list in the scope outside the function `evaluate`. I dislike this the most.

1. Do you think it's a good idea?
2. Do you have a better solution?
3. Do you think the complexity is worth it?

I will try and create more context here as to why I want this. I have implemented this idea in my package `async_v20` found [here](https://github.com/jamespeterschinner/async_v20). I have written docs [here](http://async-v20.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I left this out as I felt it was a distraction from the concept.

JSON from the server does get parsed into a python dict. Though `aiohttp` does this for me.

When the server sends JSON:

- All attributes are converted to snake_case via a dictionary lookup
- Time data is turned into a pandas.TimeStamp (requires extra parsing)

In some cases there may be 5000 objects to instantiate or objects may be nested around 3 deep. Objects get instantiated in this [module](https://github.com/jamespeterschinner/async_v20/blob/master/async_v20/definitions/base.py).

This example runs a benchmark:

```
from time import time

class Time(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.end = time()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start

def lazy_evaluate(func, *args, **kwargs):
    acc = []
    def evaluate():
        if acc == []:
            print('EVALUATING')
            acc.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return acc[0]
    return evaluate



class JitAttributes(object):

    foo = property(lambda self: getattr(self, '_foo')())
    bar = property(lambda self: getattr(self, '_bar')())
    baz = property(lambda self: getattr(self, '_baz')())

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self._foo = foo
        self._bar = bar
        self._baz = baz

class Attributes(object):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz


a = 500 # Careful making this too big!
b = a * 2
c = b * 2

print('RUNNING JitAttributes')
repeats = range(100000)

with Time() as t:
    for _ in repeats:
        JitAttributes(
            lazy_evaluate(list, range(a)),
            lazy_evaluate(list, range(b)),
            lazy_evaluate(list, range(c)),
        )

print('TOOK ', t.interval, ' seconds')


print('RUNNING Attributes')

with Time() as t:
    for _ in repeats:
        Attributes(
            list(range(a)),
            list(range(b)),
            list(range(c)),
        )

print('TOOK ', t.interval, ' seconds')
```

**Outputs:**

```
RUNNING JitAttributes
TOOK  0.2956113815307617  seconds
RUNNING Attributes
TOOK  4.880501985549927  seconds
```

**Console demonstration:**

```
>>> jit_instance = JitAttributes(
...                 lazy_evaluate(list, range(a)),
...                 lazy_evaluate(list, range(b)),
...                 lazy_evaluate(list, range(c)),
...             )
>>> jit_instance.foo
# EVALUATING            <- Only evaluates once :)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, ... ]
>>> jit_instance.foo
# [0, 1, 2, 3, ... ]
>>> non_jit_instance = Attributes(
...                 list(range(a)),
...                 list(range(b)),
...                 list(range(c)),
...             )

>>> non_jit_instance.foo
# [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
>>> non_jit_instance.foo
# [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

**Update**

New [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184573/python-jit-container-type) following on from this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a problem with your code, in that the code seems unrelated to the problem statement you give at the top.

You say you are "working on a REST API, where I currently create python objects from the JSON data returned by the server. Though not all attributes of the created objects will be called upon in user code."

None of your code involves REST, or JSON. So while it's an interesting demonstration of certain parts of Python, it doesn't much address your issue.

IMO, the feasibility of what you are discussing is going to be determined by the nature and character of the JSON data, and the REST API. Parsing JSON is generally a one-shot deal. If you get JSON data like this:

```
'{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }'
```

how would it benefit you to "defer" the evaluation or construction of the `age` and `city` attributes? It would make far more sense to just parse and assign them all.

On the other hand, if your API returns a list of 1,000's of, say, homes with lat/long coordinates, and part of the object initialization process involves computing the distance from a given origin address, then perhaps delaying the computation or delaying object instantiation makes sense.

Please share with us the nature of the problem you're really trying to solve, and we'll be able to comment effectively on whether your proposed solution is a good idea.

**EDIT:**

I had a look at your linked code. The key was, I think, in the `helpers.py:get_attribute()` function.

You appear to be re-implementing the behavior of the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) or `__getattribute__` dundermethods. I suggest that you look at implementing a simpler approach, where you store (say) '_attrname' as the lazy-evaluating function, and use `__getattr__` to expand that value into 'attrname' when you fetch it the first time.

Since Python will check for `obj.attrname` and only call `obj.__getattr__()` if not found, this would provide the advantage of doing the subsequent lookups in C code rather than Python.

Comment: Ok, fair point. I updated my post

Comment: Edited. That code is pretty opaque, which seems to be characteristic of ORM code. :( But I think __getattr__ might be your friend. qv.

Comment: That's a great suggestion! Thanks. Mmm I started to re-evaluate that whole ORM code. I got it working once and forgot about it...

Truly valuable feedback!

Comment: After making your suggested changes, my test suite runs around 10 seconds faster than previously. From ~46 to ~35, not the best benchmark but a nice indication. WooHoo!

Comment: 25 percent is nothing to sneeze at, especially for a simple change like that. I'd suggest that you create a benchmark using JSON data - perhaps reading the data from a file instead of the web, to factor out connectivity problems - and run that under cProfile as a follow-on review.

Comment: Yes, I have just created a new benchmark and it's exciting! Will write up a new post soon

Comment: Edit your review to include the link to the new review.

Comment: Never mind. Just know your suggestion got me a 66% improvement when simulating 1000 simultaneous requests. (when no attributes were accessed).  Needless to say i'm pretty happy with it. Benchmark code: https://gist.github.com/jamespeterschinner/5fb472f7e1871bd10ec6309d544eb810

Comment: There's a possible bug in your `Array` class: `one_to_may` instead of `one_to_maNy` (note: N). Not sure if it gets referenced anywhere. ALSO: I was looking at that because you always instantiate the array elements. I think you can get some more performance if you override `__getitem__`, `__contains__`, and `__iter__` (and maybe `__reversed__` for completeness) to allow you doing the same trick with deferring object creation until absolutely necessary. Just stick the entire `items` list passed to `__new__` on the array object until you do a lookup, iterate or a search (contains).

Comment: Yes, that was a bug! (Not referenced else where). Yes you are also correct that all `Array` objects are instantiated. Though with objects with lazy attributes. This suggestion, would take it to the next level though! I'll give it a crack. Thanks.

Comment: I created a new review with the above suggestion. (And snuck in the benchmark). Link is in the main body.